# ngModel on button, buttons view reloads everytime i change its state

Tags: html, angular

I have the following group of toggle-buttons:

```
<div *ngFor="let minute of state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes | keyvalue">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" ngbButtonLabel>
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="state.minutes.subTab='specificMinutes'"
             [ngModel]="state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes.get(minute.key)"
             (ngModelChange)="state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes.set(minute.key, $event)"
             (change)="setCronMinutes()" ngbButton>{{minute.key}}
    </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the buttons view reloads everytime i change something, which results in annoying flickering like seen in this [gif](https://gyazo.com/45052accafabde24093ceb44a150e6e5).

This is caused by

```
[ngModel]="state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes.get(minute.key)"
(ngModelChange)="state.minutes.specificMinutes.selectedMinutes.set(minute.key, $event)"
```

But is there a way to keep that functionality without that flickering?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you use ngModel directive, you bind it to a component property (where getter/setter is defined). It seems you also attached an event handler on changed event. Also you can use [(ngModel)] which handles the get/set for the binded property.
I'm not sure what every of your binded methods are doing, so it is hard to investigate the underlying cause. Can you provide your components logic to get a better understanding of your code?

Comment: I find it interesting, that if I bind ngModel to an element of a boolean array, it provides a weird result (turning on checkboxes which hasn't been touched yet, and model update seems unconnected as well), but when you wrap your data in a model class (pure ts class), where you bind your checkbox to this property, everything works as intended, no flickering and the model update looks alright as well